# How to get HttpOnly cookie using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, session-cookies

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parser {
    private String viewState;
    private String eventValidation;
    Map<String, String> cookies;


    public void login() throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/";
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url + "Login.aspx");
        updateViewState(connection);
        try {
            Connection.Response res = connection
                    .data("DWC$DWMessages", "")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                    .data("DWC_NotificationToolTip_ClientState", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$LoginTypes", "Guest")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$TextBoxUserName", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$TextBoxPassword", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$ButtonLogin", "Login")
                    .data("LoginWebPart_LanguageContextMenu_ClientState","")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
            cookies = connection.request().cookies();
            System.out.println(cookies);


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the printed cookie list**

```
{AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1, 11f5b7bb-885f-4c81-808d-7d5ae64248f1=DWSessionLoginID=6251bf1c-010f-4219-9a2f-5846d8f77907}
```

**This is described as an httpOnly cookie. How can I get it?**
[image: Cookie in Chrome]